# get cpu usage in a script in osx

Tags: ruby, macos, system, cpu-usage

On linux, I can get the current CPU usage out of `/proc/stat`; is there an equivalent for OSX? Or some utility that returns easy-to-parse and consistent output? I need it in a Ruby program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sysctl` is easy to parse; you can get the load average by inspecting the `vm.loadavg` value.

```
$ sysctl vm.loadavg
vm.loadavg: { 0.57 0.80 0.85 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways, all I know rely on command-line tools:

- `$` [`top`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28software%29)
- `$` [`system_profiler`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Information)
- `$ iostat -1`

If you want to keep the parsing effort low, try to reduce the output by applying useful parameters to the tools.